# Possible to traverse the children of a Firebase node in reverse order?

Tags: firebase

I'm looking into implementing an in-firebase index as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559689/534086, and trying to figure out how to deal with sorting data in descending order.  Is it possible if you have a node with children 'a', 'b', 'c' to retrieve them 'c', 'b', 'a'?  (while still being able to retrieve them in the original order as well?)

If it's not possible to traverse the node both forwards and backwards and I need to create two indexes, is their an easy algorithm for generating keys that sort in reverse lexographic order?  For numbers, I think you can multiply by -1, but not sure how to handle strings...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a "reverse()" query similar to how "limit()" works now. Firebase can't do this yet, but we're planning to add it.

Depending on your use case, it might be pretty simple for you to get around this though. If, for instance, you're using Firebase's sorting to keep a list in order that is being displayed to the user, you could simply modify the display logic to render things backward (prepend items instead of append for instance). If you're querying to select a window of data out of a large set of children (say, to get the first 10 items out of a long list), the sort order shouldn't be important -- your start and end points for the query will remain the same except they'll be reversed.

Comment: Yeah, "reverse()" would be perfect.  In terms of work arounds, the second case (large set of children, sometimes I want the first few items, sometimes I want the last few) is what I'm interested in.  Not sure I understand your suggestion... are you saying that .startAt(100).endAt(20) will iterate backwards from 100 to 20? (which would be awesome)

Comment: I'm suggesting you can do startAt(20).endAt(100) and then just render them backwards.

Comment: @andrewlee promises promises promises.  "We're going to add a reverse() and an offset() soon!  We promise!"  1 1/2 years later we're still stuck on the same issues.  :) Your solution doesn't work for pagination of large sets of data!

Comment: Do you still plan to add `reverse()`? Could really use it now!

Comment: Please Firebase team, add a reverse feature to queries!

Comment: Is this feature out yet?

Comment: After 2.5 years, we are still waiting reverse() feature :(

Comment: @AndrewLee , can you give an update about the reverse queries roadmap? Thanks

Comment: @AndrewLee 2016 is ending, is this implemented yet?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `limitToLast()` and sort the result set yourself?
I know this kind of thing works if you happen to be using Angular, where `items` is a Firebase array object on the $scope;

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'-fieldName'"> {{ item.fildName }}</li>
```