# Firebase set by priority

Tags: angularjs, firebase

My following piece of code writes a piece of data to firebase using priorities. This is all great and good. However I want to be able to arrange my list in reverse priority order? I understand that FB treats ordering as lowest first and higher further down the list... is there anyway of reversing this?

```
newMessageRef.setWithPriority({
  'message': $scope.place.name + " has been edited",
  'updated': $scope.place.updated,
  'userid': Auth.signedInAs().id}, $scope.place.updated);
```

EDIT - I know I can add a custom "reverse" filter to my ng-repeat which does work but you can briefly see the "shuffle" taking place. Would be great to arrange the data at source in the order of most recently added/edited items at the top. Almost the opposite to doing an array style .push()

Comment: You can't reverse the results yet. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126360/possible-to-traverse-the-children-of-a-firebase-node-in-reverse-order) for more details

Comment: Hey Nick! Is there some reason you can't just put a `-` in front of the value to reverse them? E.g. `5` becomes `-5`, et al. You can also use `endAt().limit(x)` to grab the last `x` records (i.e. the highest prorities). Do either of those help?

Comment: @Kato - I tried that and at the time it didn't work. May give it another go :-)