# What is the best method to exclude data and query parts of data in a Swift Firebase query?

Tags: database, swift, firebase

I am querying users from Firebase and would like to know the best method to query all users excluding the current `ref.authData.uid` . In parse its read like this......

```
query?.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
query?.whereKey("username", containsString: self.searchTXTFLD.text)
```

Also, is there any Firebase query type similar to Parse's containsString?

Comment: As Frank says in his answer, there is no searching within a string. However, you can roll your own [Searching in Firebase without server side code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867185/searching-in-firebase-without-server-side-code/33881832#33881832). See my answer there. As far as omitting the current user, there are ways to do that but it depends on if you are doing a query or observing the node. If we had more data as to what you are after, we can provide better direction.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to retrieve only items from Firebase that **don't** match a certain condition. You'll have to retrieve all items and exclude the offending ones client-side. Also see [is it possible query data that are not equal to the specified condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582223/is-it-possible-query-data-that-are-not-equal-to-the-specified-condition)

There is also no *contains* operator for Firebase queries. This has been covered many times before, such as in this question: [Firebase query - Find item with child that contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string)