# Realtime searching on firebase Query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am the query to search data real time. Its Working OK but the problem is that i want to search data weather it start from first letter or letter in between
 for example:
I want to search Stack overflow. wheater I put "S" or "o" any charter is present in this string. It will retrieve "Stack overflow".

```
//the query I use.
 mQuery =mdatabase.orderByChild("branchname").startAt(searchContent)
 .endAt(searchContent 
 + "\uf8ff");
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as duplicate as it's been asked several dozen times. Just do a search on [Firebase]string search or [Firebase]wildcard. There are LOTS of questions and examples of how to approach this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching in Firebase without server side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867185/searching-in-firebase-without-server-side-code)

Comment: the link you give is not help ful for me

Comment: It should be and it (and the additional links provided) are a wealth of solutions that answer your question. Again, searching here on SO for similar questions will reveal a plethora of options.

Comment: buddy i post this question after trying lots of solution Given in SO but its not work . that why I post this question and my question is bit of diffent than other question