# how to filter android listview items with firebase query?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase startAt query but It does not doing right filtering for instance if i want to search product name "Milk" it did'not showing item named "milk" because of lower case so how to implement it so it could work for both cases?

```
b = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.querybutton);

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Firebase  ref = new Firebase("https://socialshopping.firebaseio.com/Food/Product");
        Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchP.getText().toString());

        mActiveListAdapter  = new ActiveListAdapter(getActivity(), Product.class, R.layout.single_active_list, queryRef);
        mListView.setAdapter(mActiveListAdapter);
    }
});
```

Comment: I wrote a quick answer, then realized we'd seen better answers before. So I'll mark as a duplicate of one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase is *not* a search engine. Trying to pretend that it is, will just lead to an awful experience. But it is a NoSQL database, which means you can build many types of applications on it. Including many search scenarios.

You have two main options:

1. Stay within Firebase
2. Use an external search engine in combination with Firebase

If you stay within Firebase, you'll have to store the data in the way you want to query it, i.e. store them all lowercase and then translate the search terms to lowercase too.

See also:

- [Firebase and indexing/search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search)
- [How to perform sql "LIKE" operation on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase/22522874#22522874)