# Firebase and querying for a term in Swift

Tags: swift, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for my app and am trying to query the contents of my database. I am using the following query:

```
DataService.dataService.BASE_REF.child("Posts").
    child(selectedComment.commentKey).child("comments").
    queryOrderedByChild("userComment").queryEqualToValue(comment).
    observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
```

For eg. if I am searching for the term "bose", then only bose shows up, but "Bose", "BOSE" & "Bose XYZ" won't show up. How would I go about querying such that all of the above show up when I query "bose"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `queryEqualToValue`, you will only get results where the `userComment` matches exactly with the value you specified.

If you want results where `userComments` starts with the value, you should use a combination of `queryStartingAtValue` and `queryEndingAtValue`:

```
DataService.dataService.BASE_REF.child("Posts").
    child(selectedComment.commentKey).child("comments").
    queryOrderedByChild("userComment")
    .queryStartingAtValue(comment). queryEndingAtValue(comment+"\uF8FF")
    observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
```

This gives you a range of results, from starting with `comment` to those starting with `comment` followed by the last unicode character.

But this still won't match uppercase and lowercase results. If you want that, you will have to store the data in a uniform case to enable searching. The Firebase Database is more focused on realtime data synchronization than on completeness of its (text) search capabilities.

Also see:

- [Case insensitive sorting with Firebase orderByChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643459/case-insensitive-sorting-with-firebase-orderbychild)
- [firebase query methods startAt() taking case sensitive parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590937/firebase-query-methods-startat-taking-case-sensitive-parameters)
- [how to filter android listview items with firebase query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015762/how-to-filter-android-listview-items-with-firebase-query/36017195#36017195)

Comment: Thanks. I get - Can't call queryStartingAtValue: after queryStartingAtValue or queryEqualToValue was previously called' - when I try this.

Comment: I guess you meant
queryStartingAtValue(comment).queryEndingAtValue(comment+"\u{F8FF}"). That works. THanks.

Comment: Yup, that was a copy-paste-forgot-to-modify. Thanks for catching.