# Searching in Firebase Server-Side

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android App, the user wants to search for a book by its book name(title) . Now the problem that I face is that the user's will not always ,rather, most likely not be equal to the book name that is already there for various books posted by various other users .

So how do I search for books having the same book name without taxing the client's phone.

For example

[image]

If I use Firebase's native OrderByChild().equalTo() function , the user will have to explicitly type "ABC".But I want to make sure that my app returns this Book even when the user just types "abc " or "a" .

EDIT:- If your are gonna suggest me to write some server-side code , please help me on how I should proceed because I have read the other questions and still understood nothing.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
 .getReference("BookFair").orderByChild("bookName").startAt("Abc").endAt("abc");

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called Full-text search. Unfortunately, firebase does not provide this feature out-of-the-box.

[This link might give you a idea of what you need to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559689/4646227)

Basically you need to setup another server for indexing your content.

[Check this out if you need an idea about full text search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search)