# Filtering by content query Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an activity to search content in the FirebaseDatabase.
I want to use a Query to get the tuples which CONTAIN the string `searchBoxInput`.
I have tried the code below but it only returns the tuplas which start witch `searchBoxInput`, not which CONTAIN

```
private EditText searchInputText;
String searchBoxInput = searchInputText.getText().toString();

final Query query = ref
                .orderByChild("title")
                .startAt(searchBoxInput)
                .endAt(searchBoxInput + "\uf8ff");
```

How can I do it? Thanks :)

Comment: The Firebase database only support prefix queries: finding results that start with a certain string. It doesn't support "contains" queries, or many other full-text search types. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search

Comment: And What do you recommend me to make what I want?

Comment: The most common approach is to use a third-party search provider, either self-hosted (such as Elastic Search) or cloud-hosted (such as Algolia). For a sample for Elastic Search, see https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flashlight For a general approach for a Algolia  (on Cloud Firestore, the approach is very similar), see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search.