# what can i do for fulll test search with firebase or best way to connect mongodb full text search with firebase

Tags: mongodb, firebase

what can i do for full text search with firebase or best way to connect to mongodb full text search with firebase?

Comment: Firebase has 18+ products, two of which are databases, neither of which supports full-text search at the moment. For Firestore, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search. For Realtime Database, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search/10559689#10559689. And for both, have a look at more results from https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+full+text+search

Comment: If your data is stored in MongoDB, there would be no reason to connect to it from Firebase - you can query MongoDB Directly with REST calls or use a SDK like Realm to query with. Optionally as @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned above, there area  number of ways you can search Firebase as well. The question is pretty broad so it's really not answerable.